# Amazon EC2 Instance Remotely Start

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-access

Can someone elaborate more on the details of how to remotely start a EC2 instance remotely?

I have a Linux box set up locally, and would like to set up a cronjob on it to start an instance in Amazon EC2. How do I do that?

I've never worked with API's, if there are ways to use API's, can someone please explain how to do so...

Answer (score 4):

Pretty Simple.

1. Download EC2 API. There is a CLI with it.
2. keep `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY` and `EC2_CERT` in as your envt variables, where they are `private key` and `certificate` files that you generate from EC2 console.
3. then call `ec2-reboot-instances instance_id [instance_id ...]`

Done.

Refer: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RebootInstances.html

---

**Edit 1**

> Do I download this directly onto my Linux box? And how do I access the CLI on the linux box of the EC2 API? Sorry to ask so many questions, just need to know detailed steps of how to do this.

1. Yes. Download it from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351)
2. If you have unzipped the API in `/home/naishe/ec2api`, you can call `/home/naishe/ec2api/bin/ec2-reboot-instance <instance_id>`. Or event better set unzipped location as your envt variable `EC2_API_HOME` and append `$EC2_API_HOME/bin` to your system's `PATH`.

Also, try investing some time on [Getting Started Doc](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html) which is amazingly simple.

Comment: Do I download this directly onto my Linux box? And how do I access the CLI on the linux box of the EC2 API?

Sorry to ask so many questions, just need to know detailed steps of how to do this.

Comment: I've downloaded the file, extracted it. 

now I tried to call the instance to start: /home/naishe/ec2api/bin/ec2-start-instance <instance_id>

but it didn't work. what other steps would I need to take in place to start the ec2 instance?

Comment: what's the error you get. BTW, `/home/naishe` was just an example :) it's my home directory.

Comment: I've got an error that looks something like this:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd.

Also, whenever I try to enter the command: "./ec2-cmd" it will keep giving me errors like JAVA_HOME not set or some other variable not set. But that usually goes away after I re-set the variable. 

But I still can never get past the error of: 

Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazon.aes.webservices.client.cmd.